# NPoco InsertBulk() took 45 *minutes* to insert 20,000 records

Tags: c#, winforms, bulkinsert, npoco

I'm developing a Winforms app that currently uses DataTables/DataAdapters with emphasis on importing/processing delimted text into an embedded SQL Server Compact database.

It works, but I'm not crazy about passing DataRows around my app rather than POCOs. I thought I'd peek into the world of ORMs for comparison. NPoco looked good because it had explicit support for SQL Server Compact and simple syntax. But...

```
        List<dummy> many = new List<dummy>(20000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        {
            dummy newdummy = new dummy();
            newdummy.dummytext = $"many-{i}";
            many.Add(newdummy);
        }

        using (Database db = new Database(CONNECTIONSTRING, DatabaseType.SQLCe))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            db.InsertBulk(many);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
```

I was blown away by how slow this was! 45 minutes wall clock time. (Fetch time for the resulting 20,000 records is acceptable, but still...)

For comparison I can import 20,000+ records with a prepared command & updating parameter values in a loop in about 2.5 seconds. DataAdapter.Update is 8 seconds.

Is an ORM just not suitable for my use case, or should I try a different ORM, or...?

Comment: You can use an orm, but it needs to have *explicit* support for bulk operations. Entity Framework can with the help of additional libraries.  Internally, NPoco uses SqlBulkCopy. Your issue isn't the library:  sqlce does not support bulk operations.

Comment: Sadly, the only real bulk insert implementation on NPoco is for SqlServer. And even it is not implemented the best way - it is first converting the pocos to... data table :(

Comment: @IvanStoev i'm curious what you think the "best way" is.  `SqlBulkCopy` takes either a `DataTable`, a set of `DataRow`, or a `DbDataReader`.

Comment: @Amy Of course custom `DbDataReader` or `IDataReader` implementation - adapter on top of the passed `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: No opinion on ORM's, but if you are looking for a lightening quick way to bulk-insert into a SqlCE db, then use a SqlCeResultSet prepared from a SqlCeCommand using CommandType.TableDirect.

Comment: Does SqlCE support transactions? Can you try the same test with transactions? [NPoco Transactions](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki/SQL-Transaction-Support)

Comment: @John : `db.BeginTransaction(); db.InsertBulk(many); db.CompleteTransaction();` cut it down to 4 *seconds*. I think I can live with that. @TnTinMn 's suggestion was sub-1-second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per @John, the workaround for this problem is to wrap the bulk insert in a transaction.

```
    using (Database db = new Database(CONNECTIONSTRING, DatabaseType.SQLCe))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        db.BeginTransaction();     // <------
        db.InsertBulk(many);
        db.CompleteTransaction();  // <------
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
```